# How to access iOS UserDefaults stored data in Flutter SharedPrefrences

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sharedpreferences, nsuserdefaults

I have an **`iOS`** app already on Store, Now planning to replace it with Flutter with new version `release`.

I want to get access native app's `UserDefaults` data in Flutter code.

Using the way suggested in Flutter docs I m getting `null value`. What I have tried is:

In my `pubspec.yaml` file :

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
```

Im my `home.dart` class file I'm importing header :

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

And this is how I m trying to access data stored in **`iOS`** app from `native` app, I m using same bundle ID **(Package ID)** in flutter project to overwrite the app and it is successfully overwriting.

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getFromLocalMemory('user').then((value) =>
      userInfo = value
  );
}



Future<String> getFromLocalMemory(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String user = prefs.getString(key);
    return user;
}
```

It always returns null. **While 'user' key has data when getting from iOS native app.**

Comment: M Zubair Shamshad, have you found solution?

Comment: @Sergey using platform channels

Comment: Remember starting May 1st 2024 you are required to declare API access as per docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api#4278401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, I suggest you use platform channel method

[platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

iOS doesn't seem to allow flutter framework to access NSUserDefaults, when it didn't create it from the beginning,..

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: thank you, I will check this in detail and surely update here.

Answer (score 4):

We can use existing plugin **[native_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/native_shared_preferences)**. It allows us to access native `SharedPreferences` on **Android** and `UserDefaults` on **iOS**.
Sample code to read a value by key "SomeKey":

```
final someKey = "SomeKey";
var prefs = await NativeSharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (prefs.containsKey(someKey)) {
    print("Value for SomeKey: ${prefs.get(someKey)}");
}
```